# how nginx know from which site i was redirected to my site?

Tags: nginx

I was checking my nginx access.log and  I found bellow info.
From there is showing my redirection task: redirect to my site webcovid19.live from another portal sme.sk
How is this possible ? Is it hidden somewhere in HTML protocol ?
How webserver knows about redirection ?
Use Google Analytics the same logic ?  direct vs referral

```
85.216.x.x - - [24/May/2020:08:50:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1358 "https://domov.sme.sk/diskusie/3671287/2/koronavirus-
slovensko-minuta-po-minute-23-maj-2020.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
85.216.x.x - - [24/May/2020:08:50:52 +0000] "GET /styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 725 "https://webcovid19.live/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11
; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks Incognito :)

Issue solved:

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer